# Define a margin for specific lines in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a calculator program and i want to show the result with a tabulation, but the problem is when the text is "word wrapped", there is no spacing (because i just add "\t" to the beginning of the line). So, is it possible to define a margin for a range of text?

[image]

And this is what i want:

[image]

Thx for your help.

Comment: Looks like a custom richtextbox with special font type and dynamic number of white spaces according to the equation length.. Not so easy! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\t`, try using the [SelectionIndent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionindent(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  It uses a value in pixels:

```
rtb.AppendText("A" + Environment.NewLine);
rtb.SelectionIndent = 36;
rtb.AppendText(new string('B', 250));
rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
rtb.SelectionIndent = 0;
rtb.AppendText("C");
```